# How to merge group by list in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My List structure is: `List<KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>`

**List of** below KeyValue pairs

```
Key       Values
[PageA] [1, 3, 4] 
[PageA] [1, 3, 5] 
[PageA] [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[PageB] [1, 3, 4, 6] 
[PageC] [1, 3, 4] 
[PageC] [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

**Q:** How do i merge all values for the same keys, also removing duplicates as well, like below.

```
[PageA] [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[PageB] [1, 3, 4, 6] 
[PageC] [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

I am trying to group them first, which groups them fine but I am unable to merge those further into single keys.

```
var pages = pageData.GroupBy(p => p.Key)
```

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft: you seem to be missing the point of the question. The point is that the values in the multiple "page A" entries need to be combined. See the example output just under the question itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After grouping by your `Key` you should use `SelectMany` to merge all the collection you got from the different records. After doing so you can call `Distinct`.

```
var result = pageData.GroupBy(item => item.Key)
                     .Select(group => new 
                     { 
                         Key = group.Key, 
                         Values = group.SelectMany(item => item.Value).Distinct().ToList() 
                     }).ToList();
```

*The additional `.ToList()`s are just there to ease in debug*