# Compare properties of two elements in a list c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list : `List<NXRoute> NXRouteList = new List<NXRoute>();`

Inside this list, each "NXRoute" has a properties :

- `DestinationSignal`  (it's a string)
- `Path` which represents a list (`List<Path> pathList = new List<Path>();`)

I would like to compare the elements of `NXRouteList` according to the property `DestinationSignal`, so:

- If two elements with the same value of `DestinationSignal` are found

  ==>   before deleting the duplicate element, I would like to add the elements of its `Path` list to the`Path` list of the other element (the one that has the same `DestinationSignal`

Being new to c# programming I don't really know how to implement this

Comment: Unfortunately stackoverflow it is not a codegenerator, but you can imagine that you have to make 2 loops for compare each item of the list with the forward items. Inside you have to make a comparison of your property.

Comment: GroupBy + Select or IEqualityComparer. you should find related question with "distinct list object c#"

Comment: @BrankVictoria I think overriding Equals and GetHashCode for Path and using simple Union on lists is enough.

Comment: You can use LINQ to easily do that, google it abit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge group by list in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696623/how-to-merge-group-by-list-in-linq)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code could help you. This method creates new list of NXRoutes with no duplicates on DestinationSignal. Call to .SelectMany method aggregates all Paths for duplicated DestinationSignal values into 1 new NXRoute record.

```
public List<NXRoute> GetAllNXRoutesWithoutDuplicates(List<NXRoute> list)
{
    var nxRoutesWithSameDestinationSignals = list.GroupBy(x => x.DestinationSignal);
    return nxRoutesWithSameDestinationSignals.Select(group => new NXRoute
    {
        DestinationSignal = group.Key,
        Path = group.SelectMany(x => x.Path).ToList()
    }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188013/how-to-implement-icomparable-interface) [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.7.2) for `NXRouteList`. You can implement `CompareTo` to check that the `DestinationSignal` properties of both instances are equal.

Comment: It seems like the author doesn't really want to make a custom comparer, but just filter his input from duplicates (and aggregate the Paths those duplicates contain into 1 record).